How do I implement a complex checksum algorithm in a Purview Sensitive Information Type
I am creating a custom Sensitive Information Type in Purview.
The definition is:

Check Digit = (11 - ((
(1st digit * 9) +
(2nd digit * 7) +
(3rd digit * 5) +
(4th digit * 3) +
(5th digit * 9) +
(6th digit * 7) +
(7th digit * 5)
Mod 11)) Mod 10

It seems there is an option for a very simple checksum calculation that only involves weights and a single mod operation:
Purview Pattern Definition
But I can't see any options for creating a more complex calculation like my requirement is.
Am I missing anything?
Thanks in advance!!!

could you please provide your requirement?

To be able to implement the check digit validation in line with that formula within a custom SIT.

Do you want to implement mod 2 times?

Yeah, plus I need to do the subtraction at the start of algorithm. then mod twice at the end.

Microsoft Purview's custom Sensitive Information Type (SIT) feature has some limitations when it comes to complex checksum calculations. It currently supports only basic checksum operations involving weights and a single modulo operation like below:
Sum = digit 1 * Weight 1 + digit 2 * weight 2 + digit 3 * weight 3 + digit 4 * weight 4 + digit 5 * weight 5 + digit 6 * weight 6 + digit 7 * weight 7 + digit 8 * weight 8
Mod value = Sum % 9
If Mod value == digit 8
    Account number is valid
If Mod value != digit 8
    Account number is invalid


Check Digit = (11 - (( (1st digit * 9) + (2nd digit * 7) + (3rd digit * 5) + (4th digit * 3) + (5th digit * 9) + (6th digit * 7) + (7th digit * 5) Mod 11)) Mod 10

If above functionality is crucial for you, you can submit a feature request to Microsoft via the Microsoft Feedback Portal. For more information, you can refer to the MS document.
